# Approach to finding basis of vector space

Tags: vector-spaces

I am given the following vector space:

$$U=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R^3}:x+y+z=0\}$$

So $\forall u\in U$, we can write  $u=(x,y,-x-y)$.

I understand I can use trial and error to obtain the basis, but is there a better/more methodical approach?

Comment: What do you mean with trial and error?

Comment: @QWERTZ As in, essentially just noticing that the general term can be written in a certain way, and then showing that way is linearly independent.

Comment: Do you know how to read a basis for the null space of a matrix from its row-reduced echelon form?

Comment: @amd I've not heard of the term 'null space' before. I was under the impression that the basis can be formed from all the non-zero rows of a matrix in row reduced echelon form.

Comment: That’s for the basis of the row space. The null space is its orthogonal complement and can be constructed from the entries in columns that don’t have pivots. If you know how to do this, then you can read a basis directly from the equation $ax+by+cz=0$ because this equation says that $(x,y,z)$ is in the null space of the span of $(a,b,c)$. Alternatively, you can interpret it as saying that $U$ consists of all vectors orthogonal to $(a,b,c)$, since the l.h.s. of the eq’n is a dot product.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no "the" basis. All you need to do to find "a" basis is find a set maximal of linearly independent vectors that are in $U$.

You've already written a form for everything in $U$, and there are two free variables. So, this subspace has dimension $2$. You can get a basis as follows: first let $x=1,y=0$, second, let $x=0,y=1$. These give you basis $(1,0,-1),(0,1,-1)$.

This process will work because of what Bernard says, but I do not know if you have covered isomorphisms yet. Essentially, since this subspace has dimension $2$, it "looks like" any vector space with dimension $2$. For example, it "looks like" $\mathbb{R}^{2}$. The standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ is $(1,0),(0,1)$, so above, when I let $x=1,y=0$ and then $x=0,y=1$, I "sent" the basis of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ to that of $U$ through what is called an "isomorphism". You don't need to know what any of this means yet, in general, when you get that everything in a subspace over the field of reals can be represented with $n$ free variables, it will always work to pick the first variable $1$ and the rest $0$, the second variable $1$ and the rest $0$, and so on.

Comment: So if instead we had $U = {(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R^3}:-x+2y+z=0}$. Then the general term can be written as $(x,y,x-2y)$. Then using your method, I get $(x,y,x-2y)=x(1,0,1)+y(0,1,-2)$ which I believe does in fact form a basis of $U$. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Thank you very much, this has helped my understanding a lot.

Comment: You're very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Note that $$u = (x,y,-x - y) = x(1,0,-1) + y(0,1,-1).$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
The linear map
\begin{align}\mathbf R^2&\longrightarrow \mathbf R^3\\
(x,)&\longmapsto (x,y,-x-y)
\end{align}
induces an *isomorphism* from $\mathbf R^2$ onto $U$.

Comment: I haven't covered "isomorphism" yet, could you please expand?

Comment: It's simply a bijective linear map, and it has the property that the image of a basis by an isomorphism  is  a basis of the image.